# Extra margin showing below element?

Tags: css

For some reason, I've got an annoying padding/margin below my "large" font:

http://jsfiddle.net/o9gvgz8c/1/

I've enlarged the font more than I need, just to exaggerate the problem . The CSS in question is:

```
p::first-letter {
  font-size: 40px;font-family: 'Special Elite',cursive;padding-right: 2px
}
```

If I don't use a larger font as the start character, then its fine... but as soon as I make the first letter larger, it adds this margin in.

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to define your `::first-letter` `line-height` property as either:

```
p::first-letter {
    font-size: 50px;font-family: 'Special Elite',cursive;
    padding-right: 2px;
    line-height: 16px;
}
```

or

```
p::first-letter {
    font-size: 50px;font-family: 'Special Elite',cursive;
    padding-right: 2px;
    line-height: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/o9gvgz8c/3/

Answer (score 2):

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/o9gvgz8c/5/)

adding `line-height` will fix it

```
p::first-letter {
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family:'Special Elite', cursive;
    padding-right: 2px;
    line-height:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use relative sizing on the first letter and set the `line-height` property to the relative height `100%`, like this:

```
p::first-letter {
    font-size: 200%;
    font-family: 'Special Elite',cursive;
    padding-right: 2px;
    line-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove that gap by specifying a line-height on the `p` element :

```
p{line-height:18px;}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/o9gvgz8c/2/)**